# Is it ok to calk drywall corner joints rather than taping them?

Tags: ceiling

Instead of removing the popcorn ceiling I decided to just put a layer of drywall on top of the existing popcorn ceiling.

I noticed the worker used the caulking instead of taping where the old and the new drywall meets.

Is this okay?

[image]

Comment: Regardless of  whether or not caulk is appropriate (OK) , The quality of workmanship in that photo is **NOT OK**.

Comment: If you are going to install crown mould it is okay. The taped joint on old ceiling is still there to seal the room and be code compliant.

Comment: I don’t have plan to install crown molding..I told him before we agree on the project that I was going to paint my own to save money. Our contract is just to cover the existing popcorn so we don’t have to hire an asbestos removal. What his response is you don’t have plan to paint that is why they did the caulking only. Then I reminded him that I mentioned that I will do my painting to save money. He question me if I will do the painting right away

Comment: What did he use on the screw dimples and joints?

Comment: I would not use calking but this is really an opinion type question. I would not overlay popcorn either but removal in a residential setting is legal in my state without an abetment company or was the last time I did one.  The existing wall having texture makes mudding a corner a bit more problematic so calk may have been a way to reduce the problems. There is no code that would prevent this. And paintable calk will show compared to texture that’s why I would not do it.

Answer (score 0):

I have been seeing this a lot lately so I don't know if there is a new caulk on the market for drywall but in my experience the caulk will 'flash' under paint so it isn't going to give you a good finish and it will be noticeable. I would ask the worker what type of caulk it is and how it handles being painted.

Comment: Perhaps the OP does not know what "*flash under paint*" means.  https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer